# Rearranging rows based on custom criteria using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have to rearrange rows based on custom preference.

The table structure is like this.

```
id(primary)    top    title
1              2      t1
2              1      t2   
3              5      t3  
4              3      t4 
5              4      t5
```

Result are displayed by `ORDER BY top ASC` which gives result as.

```
id(primary)    top    title
2              1      t2
1              2      t1   
4              3      t4  
5              4      t5 
3              5      t3
```

Now i want bring this row at top and remove one row from result.

```
id(primary)    top    title
6              NULL   t6
```

And change/push-one-place-down/reassign column(top) to display result like this.

```
id(primary)    top    title
6              1      t6
2              2      t2
1              3      t1   
4              4      t4  
5              5      t5
```

I.E all previous top orderded rows are now pushed down one place and row `id=3 with top=5` is removed like `id=3 with top=NULL`.

The simple way of doing this is to reassign column(top) to desired preference, which i can't do as there are hundreds of rows to work with, so i need some automated logic in this.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Comment: Is this only for a single row? or are you looking to do this to all rows that have a NULL top value?

Comment: this is for any one row which i want display at desired position.

Comment: So basically when you do the query you want a row with a specific id to show up top then the rest be properly ordered?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  id,
  case when id=6 then 1 else top+1 end top,
  title
from
  your_table
where
  id=6 or
  top!=(select max(top) from your_table where id!=6)
order by top
```

Comment: +1 mate! I feel like giving votes to all who posts nice answers and who also give others space and share :D you are one of them!

Answer (score 0):

```
array_pop( $results ); // Remove last row
array_unshift( $results, $new_row ); // Add new row to the beginning
foreach( $results as $index => &$value )
    $value['top'] = $index+1; //Reassign top so that it matches the index of the numerical array, which will always start counting from zero
```

Comment: what if i want to display row at second place instead of top, and i want remove row from displayed result not from table.

Comment: Then that has to do with the code your use to display results. For example, if you use a for loop to display results just start with index 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
select id, ifnull(top, 0)+1, title from theTable order by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, @TOP := @TOP + 1 Top, TITLE
    FROM table1 a, (SELECT @TOP := 1) r
    ORDER BY a.TOP
  ) s
UNION 
SELECT 6, 1, 't6'
ORDER BY TOP
LIMIT 5
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c47/18)

Comment: if i want the row at any place, how can i change top values for row below the inserted row.

Comment: @TallboY oh sorry, i can;t help you with that. but you can still do it on php.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM theTable ORDER BY id = {the id you want on top} DESC, top ASC
```

or if there's multiple ones on top

```
SELECT * FROM theTable ORDER BY id in (id,id,id) DESC, top ASC
```

Comment: your second example might work, but the thing is that i have 30 result to display so i have to write all 30 ids in the desired order, is there a way to automate/pre-make/re-arrange the order.